# Vue JS how to create array of strings from FormulateInput

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using below `FormulateForm` to have input field with the submit button:

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-3">
  <FormulateInput
  name="product_codes"
  label="Style number"
  placeholder="Style number"
  />
</div>

<div class="col-12 col-md-3">
  <button
    type="button"
    class="btn btn-primary"
    @click="syncProducts"
  >
    Sync
  </button>
</div>
```

I want to sent this input data to BE as an array:

```
<script>

export default {
  name: 'SyncProducts',
  data() {
    return {
      styleCodes: [],
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

But with this code, instead of Array of String, it sends it as a String.

Comment: How would a single text input bind to an array? To me it only makes sense that it would be a string. What is the user entering?

Comment: @RobLouie well... actually the user can enter multiple `styleCodes` after a comma e.g. 1234332, 2134324, 1234 etc. each of these values should be a separate string in the array - ["1234332", "2134324", "1234"]

Comment: @mr_muscle In that case you can convert a string into an array by using `array.split(',')` method before sending to backend.

Comment: @RohìtJíndal heh... that's true. I thought I was going to have another nightmare with the `Expected Object, got Array` error if I use it explicitly. Thanks!